# Change spacing in a fraction with parentheses?

Tags: spacing, brackets, fractions

I have the exponential function that I wrote as:

```
\begin{equation}
    e^{\left(\frac{R_G^2\cdot q^2}{3}\right)}
\end{equation}
```

which appears as:

[image: 1]

and I don't like the spacing in particular the denominator space at the bottom looks weird in combination with the brackets. I tried other brackets, e.g., the "big" ones look a bit better, I guess, but too small...

```
\begin{equation}
    e^{\bigl(\frac{R_G^2\cdot q^2}{3}\bigr)}
\end{equation}
```

Here is the result:

[image: 1]

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's actually e^{-(---)}, but I guess that doesn't matter much for the question.

Comment: Take a look at `\big` and its friends from the `amsmath` package.

Comment: Avoid fractions and other large expressions in super- and subscripts as much as possible. There is *always* some more elegant way to rewrite it, e.g. as `\exp(...)`, or, if you are taking powers of something other than `e`, as something like `$a^{w}$, where $w=R_G^2 q^2/3$`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parenthesis are always symmetric around fraction. You may simple omit them or even write your equation on one of the following ways:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
    e^{(R_G^2 q^2/3)}
\end{equation}
or
\begin{equation}
    e^{R_G^2 q^2/3}
\end{equation}
or 
\begin{equation}
    \exp(R_G^2 q^2/3)
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Especially the last option cannot be recommended enough.